# Sometimes numbers in the review dropdown disappear

Tags: support, review-queues

Recently, I've stumbled upon this several times, for now I have no real idea how to reproduce but let me share so that you may suggest if it's a bug, what to look at etc.

The problem is simple: the review dropdown doesn't show numbers, only circles (see the 1st screenshot; presumably those queries that are not empty have the circles – at least they have another class, `danger-active` vs `danger-none`, see the 2d screenshot). What's I'm sure about is this is not related to some no-internet-connection problem. Reloading a page when the bug occurs doesn't seem to fix it (never fixed it for me), just sometimes it takes place and sometimes I see the dropdown in a normal state, with numbers in it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are seeing a version of an A/B test on the review popup. The version you are getting does not have the numbers.

Comment: @Oded I see. Can I see some more info about it somewhere? (I have very little idea about A/B testing at SO, places where to provide feedback, ability to switch between versions etc)

Comment: This site is where you provide feedback. The point of an A/B test is to see how people (in aggregate) react to changes - allowing people to switch between versions would invalidate the test, so it is not possible.

Comment: Ok, I'd vote against this change. (should I post such complains with the `discussion` tag?)

Comment: Again, this is **being tested**. Until we (SO) know the result of the test, there's nothing to vote against. If the test shows improvements in the metrics we care about, a change will likely happen, if not, it won't happen. By all means **once it happens**, make your post. But posting against *one option* in an A/B test before the test has been concluded and a change has occurred won't accomplish anything.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. I thought testing is a process when feedback is collected, haven't thought about metrics in this case. The only confusion left is – how do I know it's no longer A/B test? It's not indicated that I'm seeing a change this due to A/B testing. (doesn't seem that it's indicated in DOM in a hidden way either)

Comment: That's a fair point. I believe the A/B test is scheduled to stop some time this week, at which point, if you still see it, that would mean it has been a chosen - there will likely be a meta post about that.